# Read exactly n bytes unless EOF?

Tags: go, buffer

I'm using a function that returns an `io.Reader` to download a file from the Internet.

I want to process the file in exactly 2048 chunks until it's no longer possible because of EOF.

The `io.ReadFull` function is almost what I want:

```
buf := make([]byte, 2048)

for {
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(reader, buf); err == io.EOF {
        return io.ErrUnexpectedEOF
    } else if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Do processing on buf
}
```

The problem with this is that not all files are a multiple of 2048 bytes, so the last chunk may only be  e.g. 500 bytes, `io.ReadFull` will therefore return `ErrUnexpectedEOF` and the last chunk is discarded.

A function name to summarize what I want could be **io.ReadFullUnlessLastChunk**, so `ErrUnexpectedEOF` is not returned if the reason that `buf` cannot be filled with 2048 bytes, is that the file is EOF after e.g. 500 bytes. However, in any other case `ErrUnexpectedEOF` should be returned as a problem has occured.

What could I do to accomplish this?

Another problem is that reading only 2048 bytes at the time directly from the network seems to have much overhead, if I could get 256 KB from network into a buffer, and then take the 2048 bytes I need from that buffer instead, that would be better.

Comment: Is there a reason [io.LimitReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader) won't work for you?

Comment: ReadFull() doesn’t discard the last chunk. It reads the remaining data but also returns the EOF error.

Comment: You seem to know the exact behavior you want, which isn't a typical use case -- why not just implement the function which would be very few lines of code?

Comment: @Flimzy io.LimitReader doesn't seems to guarantee that I will get exactly 2048 bytes, sometimes it's less even though the file is not EOF.

Comment: @jimB I know what I want, but not how to get there unfortunately.

Comment: @BillSmith124: you can click on the function in the docs, and it will show you the source (or go to the definition in whatever editor you're using): https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=10817:10883#L294 -- just remove the unwanted conditionals.

Comment: @BillSmith124: What gives you that impression?

Comment: @Flimz: After more testing I see that io.LimitReader may be exactly what I want, but for some reason I need to empty `reader` with ioutil.ReadAll and then create a second reader with bytes.NewReader that I pass to io.LimitReader, if I pass the original reader it won't work as many times only 2030 bytes are available?

Comment: Well, yes, using a partially-consumed io.Reader is rarely what you want.

Comment: @Flimzy But I have read that it's bad pratice to use ioutil.ReadAll and you should write your Go programs to handle streams instead, so wouldn't io.Reader always be partially-consumed? What can I do to avoid running out of bytes from io.Reader? Sorry about all the (stupid) questions I'm very new to Go, so I have much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func readChunks(r io.Reader) error {
    if _, ok := r.(*bufio.Reader); !ok {
        r = bufio.NewReader(r)
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 2048)
    for {
        n, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:cap(buf)])
        buf = buf[:n]
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                return err
            }
        }

        // Process buf
        fmt.Println(len(buf))

    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fName := `test.file`
    f, err := os.Open(fName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    err = readChunks(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```